# Why do mutable borrow errors disappear when refining the type of a function pointer variable

Tags: rust, function-pointers, mutable, deque

In my function I need to rotate a `VecDeque` a certain amount of times, always in the same direction that depends on the input, with a value that never changes. So I started envisioning a solution like the following, where I can just assign the right rotation function to a function pointer and call it inside the loop to avoid repeating a useless branching.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a2a2b5db45534d60e72742f32b5f2e50))

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn example(k: isize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut queue: VecDeque<usize> = VecDeque::from(vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    let mut order = Vec::new();
    let rotation = 1 - k;
    let (amount, rotate) = match rotation >= 0 {
        true => (
            rotation as usize,
            VecDeque::rotate_right as fn(_, _),
        ),
        _ => (
            rotation.unsigned_abs(),
            VecDeque::rotate_left as fn(_, _),
        ),
    };

    while !queue.is_empty() {
        rotate(&mut queue, amount % queue.len());
        order.push(queue.pop_front().unwrap());
    }

    order
}
```

This would have worked, but as soon as I wrote the loop I got all manners of errors related to mutable and immutable borrows of `queue`. After some fiddling and the help of other people, it seems the most reasonable way is to write the code like this, with the differences highlighted by comments.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea30e14ac656d5859d4216b6d4e686fd))

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn example(k: isize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut queue: VecDeque<usize> = VecDeque::from(vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    let mut order = Vec::new();
    let rotation = 1 - k;
    let (amount, rotate) = match rotation >= 0 {
        true => (
            rotation as usize,         
            VecDeque::rotate_right as fn(&mut _, _),
        ),                        // HERE ^
        _ => (
            rotation.unsigned_abs(), 
            VecDeque::rotate_left as fn(&mut _, _),
        ),                       // HERE ^
    };

    while !queue.is_empty() {
        let len = queue.len();

        rotate(&mut queue, amount % len);
                             // HERE ^
        order.push(queue.pop_front().unwrap());
    }

    order
}
```

Now, why exactly is the `&mut` required as if it provided a better suggestion for allowing the compiler to correctly infer the type of the function pointer? And inside the loop I also need to assign the current length of the queue to a separate variable first, but if I were in a case with simpler code it would have worked regardless like in the first snippet.

Comment: The requirement to get `queue.len()` to a separate variable is [a known limitation](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2017/03/01/nested-method-calls-via-two-phase-borrowing/) of the current borrow checker, which ended up not being solved by NLL, but should be solved by Polonius. On the other hand, the requirement to change `fn()` signature is quite mysterious.

Comment: Likely the additional `&mut` nudges the compiler to make the function type generic over the referenced lifetime rather than trying to select a single lifetime. This comes up with closures all the time.